# How can I test caching and cache busting?

Tags: php, apache, caching

In PHP, I'm trying to steal a page from the Rails playbook (see 'Using Asset Timestamps' [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)):

> By default, Rails appends assets'
> timestamps to all asset paths. This
> allows you to set a cache-expiration
> date for the asset far into the
> future, but still be able to instantly
> invalidate it by simply updating the
> file (and hence updating the
> timestamp, which then updates the URL
> as the timestamp is part of that,
> which in turn busts the cache).
>
> It‘s the responsibility of the web
> server you use to set the far-future
> expiration date on cache assets that
> you need to take advantage of this
> feature. Here‘s an example for Apache:

```
  # Asset Expiration
  ExpiresActive On
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
```

If you look at a the source for a Rails page, you'll see what they mean: the path to a stylesheet might be `"/stylesheets/scaffold.css?1268228124"`, where the numbers at the end are the timestamp when the file was last updated.

So it should work like this:

1. The browser says 'give me this page'
2. The server says 'here, and by the way, this stylesheet called `scaffold.css?1268228124` can be cached for a year - it's not gonna change.'
3. On reloads, the browser says 'I'm not asking for that css file, because my local copy is still good.'
4. A month later, you edit and save the file, which changes the timestamp, which means that the file is no longer called `scaffold.css?1268228124` because the numbers change.
5. When the browser sees that, it says 'I've never seen that file! Give me a copy, please.' The cache is 'busted.'

I think that's brilliant. So I wrote a function that spits out stylesheet and javascript tags with timestamps appended to the file names, and I configured Apache with the statement above.

Now: **how do I tell if the caching and cache busting are working?**

I'm checking my pages with two plugins for Firebug: Yslow and Google Page Speed. Both seem to say that my files are caching: "Add expires headers" in Yslow and "leverage browser caching" in Page Speed are both checked.

But when I look at the Page Speed Activity, I see a lot of requests and waiting and no 'cache hits'.

If I change my stylesheet and reload, I do see the change immediately. But I don't know if that's because the browser never cached in the first place or because the cache is busted.

How can I tell?

### Update: It's working!

If anyone's interested, I just wrote [a blog post explaining the details](http://sleeplessgeek.blogspot.com/2010/03/rails-caching-and-cache-busting-in-php.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `firebug` you will see `304 Not Modified` for cached pages.

Check you have implemented [these measures](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html) in `Apache` - I've found you need a mixture of settings to accommodate all browsers.

Comment: Right! OK, I see that now - it's in the Net panel. I get `304 Not Modified` for everything that's cached. If I make a trivial change to a file, on the next reload I see it as `200 OK`. The reload after that, it's back to `304 Not Modified`.